# Azure Stream Analytics Querying JSON

Tags: json, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have a problem writing a query to extract a table out of the arrays from a json file: The problem is how to get the information of the array “clientPerformance” and then make them all in a normal sql table.

The file looks like this:

```
"clientPerformance":[  
        {  
         "name":"opportunity",
         "clientProcess":{  
            "value":3620000.0,
            "count":1.0,
            "min":3620000.0,
            "max":3620000.0,
            "stdDev":0.0,
            "sampledValue":3620000.0
         },
         "networkConnection":{  
            "value":10000.0,
            "count":1.0,
            "min":10000.0,
            "max":10000.0,
            "stdDev":0.0,
            "sampledValue":10000.0
         },
         "receiveRequest":{  
            "value":9470000.0,
            "count":1.0,
            "min":9470000.0,
            "max":9470000.0,
            "stdDev":0.0,
            "sampledValue":9470000.0
         },
         "sendRequest":{  
            "value":1400000.0,
            "count":1.0,
            "min":1400000.0,
            "max":1400000.0,
            "stdDev":0.0,
            "sampledValue":1400000.0
         },
         "total":{  
            "value":14500000.0,
            "count":1.0,
            "min":14500000.0,
            "max":14500000.0,
            "stdDev":0.0,
            "sampledValue":14500000.0
         },
         "url":"https://xxxx",
         "urlData":{  
            "base":"/main.aspx",
            "host":"xxxx",
            "hashTag":"",
            "protocol":"https"
         }
      }
   ]
```

I tried to use Get array elements method and other ways but I am never able to access to clientProcess, networkConnection.. elements

I tried to use for exampls this one:

```
Select 
GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(Input.clientPerformance, 0), 'name') AS Name,
GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(Input.clientPerformance, 1), 'clientProcess.count') AS clientProcessCount,
FROM [app-insights-blob-dev] Input
```

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Can you post some of the queries you've tried?

Comment: Select 
GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(Input.clientPerformance, 0), 'name') AS Name,
GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(Input.clientPerformance, 1), 'clientProcess.count') AS clientProcessCount,
FROM [app-insights-blob-dev] Input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I slightly edited your query to return the clientProcessCount. 
(I changed the array index from 1 to 0). Also make sure your JSON object starts with { and ends with }.

```
Select
GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(Input.clientPerformance, 0), 'name') AS Name,
GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(Input.clientPerformance, 0), 'clientProcess.count') AS clientProcessCount
FROM [app-insights-blob-dev] Input
```

For other examples to query complex objects with ASA, don't hesitate to look at this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/streamanalytics/2015/08/27/working-with-complex-data-types-in-azure-stream-analytics/).